After infusion fruits do you squeeze the alcohol out it prior to filtering
I’m soaking apples in 120 proof moonshine to try to infuse some flavor. Do I squeeze the juice out of the apples when done and prior to filtering?

Are you trying to add flavour to the apples or the liquid?
